Spring Boot Migration Performance Issues: JSP Pages Rendering Extremely Slow
I recently migrated my Spring application to a Spring Boot application using Java 17. After the migration, I've noticed a significant drop in performance, and the application has become drastically slow.
One possible cause I suspect is the use of JSP pages. Initially, I thought the slowness was due to the large amount of data being populated in the JSP pages. However, even with minimal data, such as a small button, the pages take a long time to load.
I have tried various approaches and solutions found online to improve JSP rendering speed, but none have resulted in a noticeable improvement.
Has anyone faced similar issues after migrating to Spring Boot, or does anyone have insights on resolving JSP slowness in a Spring Boot application? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

This seems to be the same question as Spring Boot Migration Performance Issues: JSP Pages Rendering Extremely Slow already asked on Stack Exchange. It isn't clear how this question relates to Ubuntu.

Yes @ChesterGillon do you have any solution for the same
